# Uploading multiple files from React to Node Js Server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have an issue while uploading multiple files from react application to Node Js server.
I built the upload on the server with multer. Tested the api on Post man and it works fine.
While uploading from React front end, I used form data to manage the payloads and files being uploaded. this is sample of the code on React

```js
 const formData = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
       console.log(photos[i]);
        formData.append(`photos[]`, photos[i]);
      }
      formData.append(`firstName`, firstName);
      formData.append(`lastName`, lastName);
      formData.append(`email`, email);
      formData.append(`password`, password);
```

On the back end (Node server)
req.files is empty but the req.body returns data with the photos as part of the payload.
This is the req.body log.

```js
 console.log(req.files) => undefined 
console.log(req.body) => {
  photos: [ {}, {}, {} ] (the files are returning inside the req.body),
  firstName: 'Test',
  lastName: 'Two',
  email: 'test111@test.com',
  password: '123456'
}
```

Note: I've used body-parser and express.json and urlencoded.
This is my form tag

```html
<form onSubmit={submitHandler} encType="multipart/form-data">
```

This is the input

```html
<input
              type="file"
              name="photos"
              className="form-control"
              multiple
              max={4}
              onChange={handleFileChange}
            />
```

Multer handler

```js
module.exports = multer({
    storage: multer.diskStorage({}),
    fileFilter: (req,file,cb)=>{
        let ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if(ext === '.jpeg' || ext ===  '.jpg' || ext ===  '.png' || ext === '.pdf' || ext === ".txt" || ext === ".doc"){
          cb(null,true)
        }else{
          cb({error:'You can not upload this type of file'},false)
        }
      }

})
```

This is my route

```js
router.post('/users/register', upload.array("photos", 4), registerValidation(), validate, UserController.registerUser);
```

Please someone help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: There are two options available, destination and filename. They are both functions that determine where the file should be stored for multer.diskStorage({})

Comment: try changing - const upload = multer(.....).array("photos", 4), and try to call upload(req, res) in the route.

Comment: I'm saving the files on S3. The upload works if I test from postman

Comment: @Immanuel I don't understand your comment

Comment: i have a suggestion .. using s3 preassigned url u can upload files from frontend to s3 directly without sending them to server.

Comment: I would have love to do this. But I'm doing a technical test. and the specification was to upload from server.

Comment: you can use formadible(https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) which is way easier then multer  on server side..

install formadible and just add fowlling middleware in route..

const attachBodyAndFiles = (req, res, next) => {
    const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {if (err) {return res.status(500).json({success: false,msg: "General Middleware File Handling Error",err})};req.files = [];for (const key in files) {if (files.hasOwnProperty(key)) {const element = files[key];req.files.push(element)}};req.body = fields;next()})}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this, by changing from body-parser to express in built.
Also I removed the encType in the form tag and passed the content type directly in headers. Thank you all for your suggestion.